# (M2EPro) Determine if FBA Order

Tags: magento-1.9, amazon, m2e

I'm using the M2Epro extension to gather ebay and amazon orders. We want to differentiate between FBA orders and MFN for Amazon Orders. I can't find a column in SQL that differentiates between FBA and MFN, but there is an option to disable adding FBA orders... so figure it must be in the system somewhere. Does anyone know?

Comment: The question describes a problem that can be reproduced when a person has m2epro...

Comment: The problem went away after digging deep into the SQL tables associated with M2Epro... not on its own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the data in `m2epro_amazon_order`. There's a column for is_afn_channel.